# Trouble with example of sequences $(f_n)_n,(g_n)_n\in\ell^1$ with $\|f_n\|_\infty\to0,\,\|f_n\|_2\to\infty$ and $\|g_n\|_2\to0,\,\|g_n\|_1\to\infty.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, proof-verification

> $\textbf{a)}$ Show that the inclusions
>   $$\ell^1\subseteq\ell^2\subseteq\ell^\infty,$$
>   are all strict.

To see that the inclusions are strict, first consider $f=(1,1,1\dots)$. Then $\|f\|_\infty=1$ so $f\in\ell^\infty$, however
$$\|f\|_2^2=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}1=\infty\quad\text{and}\quad\|f\|_1=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}1=\infty,$$
so that $f\notin\ell^2$ and $f\notin\ell^1$. Now consider $\displaystyle g=\left(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\dots\right)$. Then
$$\|g\|_2^2=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\quad\text{and}\quad\|g\|_1=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}=\infty,$$
so that $g\in\ell^2$ but $g\notin\ell^1$. Therefore, the inclusions are strict, that is, $\ell^1\subset\ell^2\subset\ell^\infty.\quad\quad\blacksquare$

> $\textbf{b)}$ Give an example of sequences $(f_n)_n$ and $(g_n)_n$ in $\ell^1$ with
>   $$\|f_n\|_\infty\to0,\,\|f_n\|_2\to\infty\quad\text{and}\quad\|g_n\|_2\to0,\,\|g_n\|_1\to\infty.$$

For the first example I cooked up the following sequence
$$f_n(k)=\frac{1}{n^{1/4}}\text{ for all }k\leq n\quad\text{and}\quad f_n(k)=0\text{ for all }k>n,$$
Then $(f_n)_n\subset\ell^1,$ and we have that
$$\|f_n\|_\infty\to0\quad\text{and}\quad\|f_n\|^2_2=\sqrt{n}\to\infty.$$
The second example is the one I am having trouble cooking up. I tried the following strange looking sequence
$$g_n(k)=0\text{ for all }k<n\text{ and all }k\geq 2n\quad\text{ and }g_n(k)=\frac{1}{k}\text{ otherwise}.$$
Then $(g_n)_n\subset\ell^1$ and we have that
$$\|g_n\|_2\to0\text{ and }\|g_n\|_1\to\infty,$$
since the $\|\cdot\|_1$-norm of $g_n$ approaches the tail of the harmonic series. $\quad\quad\blacksquare$

---

Could anyone please check if my proof of part (b) is correct?

Thank you for your time and appreciate any feedback.

Comment: @runway44 It is not true that $\|g_n\|_1 \to \infty$.

Comment: You are right. ${}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example does not work. Change the definition to $g_n(k)= 0$ for $ k<n$ as well as $k \geq n^{2}$ and $\frac 1 k$ for other $k$. To show that $\sum\limits_{k=n}^{n^{2}-1} \frac 1 k$ does  tends to $\infty$ just compare it with $\int_x^{x^{2}-1} \frac 1 t dt=\ln(x^{2}-1)-\ln (x)=\ln (x-\frac 1 x) \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this example, which is more similar to your attempt:

$$g_n(k) = \begin{cases} \frac1{n^{3/4}}, &\text{ if }n \le k \le 2n-1\\ 0, &\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Then 
$$\|g_n\|_1 = \sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} \frac1{n^{3/4}} = \frac{n}{n^{3/4}} = n^{1/4} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \infty$$
$$\|g_n\|_2^2 = \sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} \frac1{n^{3/2}} = \frac{n}{n^{3/2}} = \frac1{n^{1/2}} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$$